# Calculating the width of two elements and the space in between and make the header the same width

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have text/image sections on my website with the container only preventing the content from touching the sides on mobile so the site can span full width. On certain pages where the setup follows - https://jsfiddle.net/EikHunter/za3p3vm3/

```html
<header class="hd-Header">
  <div class="hd-Header_Inner">
    <div class="hd-Header_Body">
      <div class="hd-Header_Left">
        <div class="hd-Header_LogoContainer">
          <div class="hd-Header_Logo">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="hd-Header_Right">
        <div class="nav-Navigation">
          <ul class="nav-Navigation_Items">
            <li class="nav-Navigation_Item">
              <a href="#" class="nav-Navigation_Link">Nav 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-Navigation_Item">
              <a href="#" class="nav-Navigation_Link">Nav 2</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-Navigation_Item">
              <a href="#" class="nav-Navigation_Link">Nav 3</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-Navigation_Item">
              <a href="#" class="nav-Navigation_Link">Nav 4</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-Navigation_Item">
              <a href="#" class="nav-Navigation_Link">Nav 5</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>

<section class="sec-Section">
  <div class="sec-Section_Inner">
    <div class="sec-Section_Columns">
      <div class="sec-Section_Column sec-Section_Column-content">
        <div class="sec-Section_Content">
          <h1 class="sec-Section_Title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h1>
          <p class="sec-Section_Text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum, voluptate.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="sec-Section_Column">
        <div class="sec-Section_ImageContainer">
          <div class="sec-Section_Image">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

I need to calculate the distance between the two text elements including space between so that I can make the header the same width as the width of the text areas working responsively so the text areas remain centred.

[image: here]

Comment: Why can't you just used a fixed-width container for the header and the site content? And then adjust it's width using media queries? Just like a bootstrap container? The way you seem to want to do things sems overly complicated.

Comment: If you can suggest a way of structuring the CSS/HTML that allows the text to be centered vertically and horizontally of screen width then please do, but as far as I know, there doesn't seem to be a way to be able to achieve both without using Javascript to do some calculations

Comment: What are you talking about? Why does screen width matter with vertical centering?...

Comment: @felipe He has a centered container (much like Bootstrap) with blocks of 50% width text in this. He wants the images to line up to the middle of this container, but stretch out to the sides of the browser window. It's clear as day by just looking at his diagram

Comment: If you look at the jsfiddle, the sections that are text/image, the text is vertically and horizontally aligned and stays that way regardless of the screen size, until they just stack on top of each other, how do you recreate this responsively while making the header align to these sides of text, please do show me an example.

Comment: @Scoots I have achieved this with my html and CSS but there doesn't seem to be way to make the header align to the sides of the text boxes just using js, it currently spans fullwidth

Comment: I actually think I originally misunderstood the question. You have 2 text blocks which have a variable width / height, and you want it so that if these text boxes grow wider, it'll push out the width of the header above. Is that correct?

Comment: So the text always needs to be centered relative to it being half the width of the viewport because the image takes up the other half, the whole website has a container but the sole purpose of that container is to prevent the content from not having a buffer on mobile, for the pages that follow the layout of the text/image I need the header to be aligned to the furthest parts of text, and grow and shrink relative to the size of the viewport.